# Read JTextArea For Jazzy Spell Checker API

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, spell-checking

Question: Trying to get the same effect as the code below only with JTextArea so I want the JTextArea to be read and spelling suggestions to be recommended every time the user types a new misspelt  word.

Below is the working example with 'System.in' which works well.

(Vars userField = JTextArea & dic.txt is a list of the english language for the system to use for suggestions)

CODE (1)

```
public SpellCheckExample() {
    try {
      SpellDictionary dictionary = new SpellDictionaryHashMap(new File(dic.txt));

      spellCheck = new SpellChecker(dictionary);
      spellCheck.addSpellCheckListener(this);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

      while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter text to spell check: ");
        String line = in.readLine();

        if (line.length() <= 0)
          break;
        spellCheck.checkSpelling(new StringWordTokenizer(line));
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

What I have Been trying:

CODE (2)

```
public void spellChecker() throws IOException{


      String userName = System.getProperty("user.home");
      SpellDictionary dictionary = new SpellDictionaryHashMap(new File(userName+"/NetBeansProjects/"+"/project/src/dic.txt"));
      SpellChecker spellCheck = new SpellChecker(dictionary);
      spellCheck.addSpellCheckListener(this);


    try{
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(userField.getText());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(sr);

    while(true){
   String line = br.readLine();

   if(line.length()<=0)
   break;
  spellCheck.checkSpelling(new StringWordTokenizer(line));


            }
   }catch(IOException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

 }
```

March 3rd 2016 (Update)

```
    public void spellChecker() throws IOException{
  // getting context from my dic.txt file for the suggestions etc.
    SpellDictionary dictionary = new SpellDictionaryHashMap(new File("/Users/myname/NetBeansProjects/LifeSaver/src/dic.txt"));
    SpellChecker spellCheck = new SpellChecker(dictionary);


    // jt = JTextField already defined in constructors and attemtpting to pass this into system and 
   InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(jt.getText().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))); 


  //spellCheck.checkSpelling(new StringWordTokenizer(line));  ""ORIGINAL"""



  // reccomending cast to wordfinder
spellCheck.checkSpelling(new StringWordTokenizer(is);
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for reasons why your current approach won't work, then have a look at [Listening for Changes on a Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) and [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for some possible solutions

As someone is bound to mention it, DON'T use a `KeyListener`, it's not an appropriate solution for the problem

Put simpler, Swing is a single threaded, event driven framework.  So anything you do which blocks the Event Dispatching Thread, will prevent it from processing new events, including paint events, making your UI unresponsive

As an event driven environment, you need to register interested in been notified when some event occurs (this is an example of [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html)) and then take appropriate actions based on those events.

Remember though, you can not make changes to a `Document` via a `DocumentListener`, so be careful there

Comment: And also do what MadProgrammer recommends as he knows his Swing.

Comment: Im having a hard time with reading the JTextField.. essentially I just put the JTextField in my JToolBar with a Button beside it etc. When Button is pressed it triggers the event. My problem is getting the JTextField readable by the system I was using this    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(jt.getText().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))); ' But it has probed to fail kind of back at the same issue now

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I have updated my Question the code I have been using is directly under the 'March 3rd 2016' at the very bottom ... I don't know really where to go with this at this point I have tried multiple different ways of trying to read the JTextField and unfortunately I'm not arriving at a solution , problem seems to be trying to get the System tactually read the JTextField appropriately

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to try to drop console UI code into an event-driven GUI, as it will never work like that. Instead you need to use GUI events to trigger your actions, not readln's.

The first thing you must decide on is which event you wish to use to trigger your spell check. For my money, I'd get the user's input in a JTextField, not a JTextArea since with the former, we can easily trap `<enter>` key presses by adding an ActionListener on the JTextField. You can always use both, and then once the text is spell checked, move it to the JTextArea, but this is exactly what I'd recommend:

- use a JTextField,
- add an ActionListener to the JTextField to be notified whenever the field has focus and enter is pressed,
- within this listener, extract the text from the JTextField, by calling `getText()` on the field
- Then run your spell check code on extracted text,
- and output the result into a nearby JTextArea.

Comment: When you're speaking of using JTextField I kind of need to use JTextArea because the way the app is imagine like a Word Document type application , unless I  misunderstood you.